# Javascript: Showing bedtimes in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, time, graph, chart.js

I want to show the bedtimes in a graph from [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-introduction).
Assume I have a array:

```
bedtimes = [2200, 2345, 2130, 2445, 2115, 2600]
//#1 = 22:00
//#2 = 23:45
//#3 = 21:30
//#4 = 00:45
//#5 = 21:15
//#6 = 02:00
```

When I have a value of `2230`, the graph dot, is **not** on the half between `22:00` and `23:00` but is on a quarter, because the graphs thinks that there are 100 units between `23:00` and `24:00` but there are actually `60` (60 minutes in 1 hour)

```
var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d")).Line(data, {
    scaleOverride: true,
    scaleSteps: 4,
    scaleStepWidth: 100,
    scaleStartValue: 2200,
    scaleLabel: function (valuePayload) {
        if(Number(valuePayload.value)===2200)    
            return '22:00';
        if(Number(valuePayload.value)===2300)    
            return '23:00';
        if(Number(valuePayload.value)===2400)    
            return '00:00';
        if(Number(valuePayload.value)===2500)    
            return '01:00';
        if(Number(valuePayload.value)===2600)    
            return '02:00';
    }
});
```

Can someone explain me how to setup the graph, that after `2359` comes `2400`,
And when the value is `2230` the graph dot is at the half between `22:00` and `23:00`

Comment: You can override the default scale of chart.js in the configuration. Maybe you can achieve your desired result with the help of this approach. See [here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration) for details.

Answer (score 0):

When you convert your integer representation of time to "minutes since midnight", then 2230 lies right in the middle of 2200 and 2300.

```
var getMinutesSinceMidnight = function(time){
    var hours = Math.floor(time/100);
    var minutes = time%100;    
    return hours*60 + minutes;
}

getMinutesSinceMidnight(2200) //returns 1320 
getMinutesSinceMidnight(2230) //returns 1350 
getMinutesSinceMidnight(2300) //returns 1380
```

You can use these values for plotting and the original integer times for labeling of the graph.

Answer (score 0):

For the hour, divide by 100:

```
var time = 2330;
var hour = Math.floor(time / 100);
```

Now subtract the result from the original time and multiply it by the proper fraction (100/60)

```
time -= (hour * 100)
var minute = (time * 100) / 60
```

jsfiddle:

```js
window.getTime = function() {
  var time = document.getElementById('time').value;
  var hour = Math.floor(time / 100);
  time -= (hour * 100);
  var minute = (time * 100) / 60;
  alert("Hour: " + hour + ", Minute: " + minute);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="time">
<button type="button" onclick="getTime()">Get Time</button>
```

This will turn 2330 into 2350, that way the dot appears half-way as expected.